# Can I transfer the RAM from a Vostro V131 to a Vostro 3460?

Tags: memory, dell-vostro

I have a Dell Vostro V131 that I don't use anymore because it's... kinda broken. I'm now using a 3460.

This 3460 does *not* have enough RAM for what I use the computer for (read: SE stuff and YT). I'd like to transfer the RAM from the V131 to the 3460, so that I don't have to buy new RAM. Is this possible? Are they compatible?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from:
https://www.cnet.com/products/dell-vostro-v131-13-3-core-i3-2330m-windows-7-pro-64-bit-2-gb-ram-320-gb-hdd-series/specs/
And:
https://www.engadget.com/products/dell/vostro/3460/specs/

Both of your laptops use DDR3 SDRAM so the memory from the V131 is compatible with the 3460.  Whether the 3460 has a spare slot for this memory is a different matter.

So you SHOULD be able to put the extra memory in.  Whether you CAN is best told by finding the memory port and opening it up with a small screwdriver.

Comment: They usually populate all the slots in laptops, so unless the modules are larger than what is already there, most likely it wont help.